# symfony2 how to override the User class with FosuserBundle?

Tags: symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

My problem is quite simple but i search for an hour without succeed, i would like to add some constraint to the UserEntity. For example, i would like to limit the length of a username

I think the best way is to not touche FOS in Vendor. I have create my own userBundle with my own layout.html etc ... But i cannot override attribut who is already existing in FosuserBundle (it's working for the layout overriding btw my userBundle is a child of FOS)
the funny thing is "id" has no problem for the overriding

My User entity :

```
<?php

namespace Diane\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**

 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Diane\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**

     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=10)
     */
    protected $username;

}
```

Fos User model :

```
<?php

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

abstract class User implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;


...

}
```

i have already try to remove :

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
```

Error message :

> Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException] Duplicate definition of column
>   'username' on entity 'Diane\UserBundle\Entity\User' in a field or
>   discriminator column mapping.

Thanks for any idea you could give me

Comment: please edit code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try AttributeOverrides `Doctrine` annotation:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Diane\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository") / class User extends 
 *
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="username",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "username",
 *              type     = "string",
 *              length   = 10
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 *
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
```

Comment: This works but it's worth noting that it breaks "php app/console doctrine:generate:entities"